# Issues with jquery function and if block

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

thanks in advance for reading my question, i have a jquery function where i use a flag variable ($act) to run an if block, but it is always zero(0) and never changes, because of that the if block does not work, any help would be appreciated

[http://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/CWF6G/](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/CWF6G/1/)

```
function recibo_pago() {

        var errores = [];
        var $checkedRecords_facts = $('.checkedRecords:checked');
        var $checkedRecords_pagos = $('.checkedRecords2:checked');
        var $f_rec = $('#fecha_recibo');
        var $n_rec = $('#numero_recibo');
        var $act = 0;

        var $CodClie = codigo_cliente;

        if ($checkedRecords_facts.length < 1) {
            errores.push('Debe Seleccionar al menos una factura');
        }

        if ($checkedRecords_pagos.length < 1) {
            errores.push('Debe Seleccionar al menos un Pago');
        }

        if ($f_rec.val() == '') {
            errores.push('Debe Ingresar la fecha del Recibo de Pago');
        }

        if (errores.length == 0) {

            $arreglo_facts = [];
            $arreglo_pagos = [];

            $checkedRecords_facts.each(function (index) {
                $arreglo_facts.push($(this).text());
            });
            $checkedRecords_pagos.each(function (index) {
                $arreglo_pagos.push($(this).text());
            });

            var $jsonString_facts = JSON.stringify($arreglo_facts);
            var $jsonString_pagos = JSON.stringify($arreglo_pagos);

            if ($n_rec.val() == '') {
                jConfirm('¿Estas seguro que desea guardar el Recibo de Pago sin Número de Control?', 'Confirmar Guardar sin Número de Control', function ($r) {
                    if ($r) {
                        //it changes value here to 1, i used console.log to see it
                        $act = 1;
                    } else {
                        $n_rec.focus();
                    }
                });                
            } else {
                $act = 1;
            }
            //Here the $act value is zero (0) and does not work the code inside the if block, help please
            if ($act == 1) {
                console.log($act);
                var datos = { facts: $jsonString_facts, pags: $jsonString_pagos, Fecha: $f_rec.val(), NoRecibo: $n_rec.val() };

                $.ajax({
                    url: direccion + 'PROG_4394/GuardarReciboPago',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: datos,
                    success: function (data) {
                        jAlert(data.mensaje, data.titulo);
                        if (data.success) {
                            jAlert("ENVIO TRUE", "PRUEBA");
                        }
                    }
                })

            }

        } else {

            var DivErrores = $('#errores');
                Errores = errores;
            if (Errores.length > 0) {
                DivErrores.html('<h1>Errores</h1>')
                    .append('<p>Verifique los siguientes errores antes de continuar</p>')
                    .append('<ul>');
                Errores.forEach(function (error) {
                    DivErrores.append('<li><p style="display: inline;">' + error + '</p>' + '</li>');
                });
                DivErrores.append('</ul><br/>');
            } else {
                DivErrores.empty();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I downvoted because you posted a huge amount of code with several `if` statements. You also mention a "flag variable" but don't tell us where it is. Are we meant to guess?

Comment: I can't be sure, but I'm going to guess that `$n_rec.val()` is not blank and `jConfirm` is a jQuery (non-blocking) dialog, so while the value may be changed on the line you noted, the rest of the code would have already executed. To check this, add `console.log()` statements to your code where your comments are and see in what order they appear.

Comment: Ricardo, make a jsfiddle, much easier to help...

Comment: @spender i marked the if with issues for you, just look for                      //Here the $act value is zero (0) and does not work the code inside the if block, help please
            if ($act == 1) {

Comment: @Sergio here you are, it's incomplete because i use a lot of tleriks grids http://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/CWF6G/

Comment: @ricardorios, but... but, where is the html in your jsfiddle?

Comment: @spender the flag variable is "$act"

Comment: @HanleEscaño here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/CWF6G/1/

Comment: @ricardorios: it's still a huge amount of code for a simple question. The question is also mis-tagged with c# and asp.net-mvc but there is no obvious connection to either. I removed my downvote, but I still have concerns about the quality of this question.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34705/lets-solve-this

Comment: @spender i used a Fiddle to show you all the code, and html, and commented the js file, look for comment that says "//The Problem is from here until..." and the end of the block code "//here..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HanleEscaño for the guidance

It is a Confirmation mode async, so i basically divided it in two functions to solve this issue

```
 function llamada_recibo_pago($jsonString_facts, $jsonString_pagos, $f_rec, $n_rec) {
        var datos = { facts: $jsonString_facts, pags: $jsonString_pagos, Fecha: $f_rec, NoRecibo: $n_rec };

        $.ajax({
            url: direccion + 'PROG_4394/GuardarReciboPago',
            dataType: "json",
            data: datos,
            success: function (data) {
                jAlert(data.mensaje, data.titulo);
                if (data.success) {
                    jAlert("ENVIO TRUE", "PRUEBA");
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

And called llamadas inside asyn function like here

```
//alert($act);
            if ($n_rec.val() == '') {
                jConfirm('¿Estas seguro que desea guardar el Recibo de Pago sin Número de Control?', 'Confirmar Guardar sin Número de Control', function ($r) {
                    if ($r) {
                        $act = 1;
                        llamada_recibo_pago($jsonString_facts, $jsonString_pagos, $f_rec.val(), $n_rec.val());
                    } else {
                        $n_rec.focus();
                    }
                });                
            } else {
                $act = 1;
            }
            //Here the $act value is zero (0) and does not work the code inside the if block, help please
            //alert($act);

            if ($act == 1) {
                llamada_recibo_pago($jsonString_facts, $jsonString_pagos, $f_rec.val(), $n_rec.val());
            }
```